# Show that $(X_n, Y_n) \stackrel d \to (X,Y).$

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

> Let $\{X_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ and $\{Y_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ be independent random variables such that $X_n \stackrel d \to X$ and $Y_n \stackrel d \to Y.$ Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are also independent. Then show that $(X_n, Y_n) \stackrel d \to (X,Y).$

In order to show that I have to use the following fact $:$

> Let $\mathscr A$ be a $\pi$-system of subsets of $\mathbb R$ such that each open set in $\mathbb R$ can be written as a countable union of sets from $\mathscr A.$ For a collection of real random variables $\{X_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ and $X,$ if $\mathbb P (X_n \in A) \to \mathbb P(X \in A)$ for every $A \in \mathscr A,$ then $X_n \stackrel d \to X.$

**My Attempt** $:$ Let $\mathcal C_X$ and $\mathcal C_Y$ be the collections of $X$-continuity sets and $Y$-continuity sets respectively.  Then using the independence, we can see that $$\mathbb P ((X_n, Y_n) \in A \times B) \to \mathbb P ((X,Y) \in A \times B),$$ for all $A \in \mathcal C_X$ and $B \in \mathcal C_Y.$ So it is natural to consider $\mathscr A = \mathcal C_X \times \mathcal C_Y,$ where $$\mathcal C_X \times \mathcal C_Y : = \{A \times B\ :\ A \in \mathcal C_X\ \text {and}\ B \in \mathcal C_Y \}.$$  Then $\mathcal A$ is clearly a $\pi$-system. But the fact which is not clear to me is whether we can able to write any open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ as a countable union of sets from $\mathscr A$ or not. Could anyone kindly shed some light on that?

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Provided that the sequences of  variables $X_n$ and $Y_n$ take values on euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$, one can use the Cramer-Wold criteria:

$$\mathbb{E}[\exp(t\cdot X_n+ t\cdot Y_n)]=\mathbb{E}[\exp(s\cdot X_n)]\mathbb{E}[\exp(t\cdot Y_n)]\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}[\exp(s\cdot X)]\mathbb{E}[\exp(t\cdot Y)]$$

Comment: You also need independence of $X_n$ and $Y_n$ for each $n$. Your wording of the problem does not make this clear. If this is satisfied, you can use characteristic functions for  a quick proof.

Comment: @geetha290krm$:$ It's not me who is wording this problem. It's an assignment problem and it is instructed to solve using the fact that I mentioned. The fact is also included in the assignment set as one of the exercises which I can able to solve using another problem in the assignment set which is the following $:$ $$X_n \stackrel d \to X \Longleftrightarrow \liminf\limits_{n \to \infty} \mathbb P \left (X_n \in U \right) \geq \mathbb P \left (X \in U \right)$$ for all open set $U \subseteq \mathbb R.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $I = (a, b)$ be an interval in $\mathbb R.$ Let $C(F_X)$ be the set of all $X$ continuity points i.e. the points where $F_X$ (cdf of $X$) is continuous. Since $C (F_X)$ is dense in $\mathbb R,$ there exist sequences $\{a_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ and $\{b_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ in $C(F_X)$ such that $a_n \searrow a$ and $b_n \nearrow b.$ Then $I = \bigcup\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} (a_n, b_n).$ So any open interval in $\mathbb R$ can be written as a countable union of sets from $\mathcal C_X.$ Similar argument holds if $X$ is replaced by $Y.$ Also note that, any open set in $\mathbb R^2$ is the countable union of open rectangles having rational vertices. Combining these two considerations, it follows that any open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ can be written as a countable union of sets from $\mathscr A,$ which is what you wanted to show.